# gradle 8.4: copy dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I'm upgrading to gradle 8.4 from 7.4. I have a task

```
task {
    copyDependencies(type: Copy) {
        from configurations.default
        into '../out/bin/lib'
    }
}
```

which copy my dependencies to '../out/bin/lib'
and I had

```
jar.finalizedBy = [copyDependencies]
```

But this is no more working. I checked already the upgrade guide but found no solution.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use the configuration `default`, but `runtimeClasspath`.